# Quantitativo de posições

Tags: r, dplyr

Preciso calcular a porcentagem de dias que estejam em determinado intervalo de valores na coluna analise (valores estão em porcentagem) em relação ao quantitativo total de dias referente aquele mês.

Inicialmente faço o levantamento de quantos dias cada mês possui, faço isso principalmente devido ao mês de fevereiro que pode variar:

```
qtd_dias_mes <- dados %>% 
  group_by(mes) %>% 
  select(analise) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(n()) %>%          
  dplyr::rename("qtd_dias_mes" = "n()")
  View(qtd_dias_mes)
```

Agora faço o levantamento de quantos dias estão entre o intervalo que seja maior que 75 e menor que 100:

```
analise_75_e_100 <- dados %>%
filter(dados$analise > 75 & dados$analise < 100) %>% 
  group_by(mes) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(n())
```

**os valores entregues pelo dplyr::summarise(n()) não contempla o mês 6 (com o dataframe completo), e ao fazer o cálculo que preciso (abaixo), acaba aparecendo o mês 6 (o que não deveria) e com valores errados a partir dele, sendo que deveria aparecer 0 para o mês 6:**

```
porc_dias_entre_75_e_100 = (analise_75_e_100$`n()` / qtd_dias_mes$qtd_dias_mes) * 100
```

de forma a simplificar minha pergunta aqui, apresentei acima o cálculo com esse intervalo, contudo irei calcular para diferentes intervalos de porcentagem, podendo aparecer menos não contemplados, devendo então serem preenchidos com zero. Quais alternativas para esses cômputos ficarem corretos?

Meus dados possuem 10957 linhas (1/1/1990 a 31/12/2019), talvez fazendo com a amostra abaixo altere o mês 6 que exemplifiquei acima, contudo o raciocínio é o mesmo.

```
> dput(head(dados, 200))
structure(list(data = c("1/1/1990", "1/2/1990", "1/3/1990", "1/4/1990", 
"1/5/1990", "1/6/1990", "1/7/1990", "1/8/1990", "1/9/1990", "1/10/1990", 
"1/11/1990", "1/12/1990", "1/13/1990", "1/14/1990", "1/15/1990", 
"1/16/1990", "1/17/1990", "1/18/1990", "1/19/1990", "1/20/1990", 
"1/21/1990", "1/22/1990", "1/23/1990", "1/24/1990", "1/25/1990", 
"1/26/1990", "1/27/1990", "1/28/1990", "1/29/1990", "1/30/1990", 
"1/31/1990", "2/1/1990", "2/2/1990", "2/3/1990", "2/4/1990", 
"2/5/1990", "2/6/1990", "2/7/1990", "2/8/1990", "2/9/1990", "2/10/1990", 
"2/11/1990", "2/12/1990", "2/13/1990", "2/14/1990", "2/15/1990", 
"2/16/1990", "2/17/1990", "2/18/1990", "2/19/1990", "2/20/1990", 
"2/21/1990", "2/22/1990", "2/23/1990", "2/24/1990", "2/25/1990", 
"2/26/1990", "2/27/1990", "2/28/1990", "3/1/1990", "3/2/1990", 
"3/3/1990", "3/4/1990", "3/5/1990", "3/6/1990", "3/7/1990", "3/8/1990", 
"3/9/1990", "3/10/1990", "3/11/1990", "3/12/1990", "3/13/1990", 
"3/14/1990", "3/15/1990", "3/16/1990", "3/17/1990", "3/18/1990", 
"3/19/1990", "3/20/1990", "3/21/1990", "3/22/1990", "3/23/1990", 
"3/24/1990", "3/25/1990", "3/26/1990", "3/27/1990", "3/28/1990", 
"3/29/1990", "3/30/1990", "3/31/1990", "4/1/1990", "4/2/1990", 
"4/3/1990", "4/4/1990", "4/5/1990", "4/6/1990", "4/7/1990", "4/8/1990", 
"4/9/1990", "4/10/1990", "4/11/1990", "4/12/1990", "4/13/1990", 
"4/14/1990", "4/15/1990", "4/16/1990", "4/17/1990", "4/18/1990", 
"4/19/1990", "4/20/1990", "4/21/1990", "4/22/1990", "4/23/1990", 
"4/24/1990", "4/25/1990", "4/26/1990", "4/27/1990", "4/28/1990", 
"4/29/1990", "4/30/1990", "5/1/1990", "5/2/1990", "5/3/1990", 
"5/4/1990", "5/5/1990", "5/6/1990", "5/7/1990", "5/8/1990", "5/9/1990", 
"5/10/1990", "5/11/1990", "5/12/1990", "5/13/1990", "5/14/1990", 
"5/15/1990", "5/16/1990", "5/17/1990", "5/18/1990", "5/19/1990", 
"5/20/1990", "5/21/1990", "5/22/1990", "5/23/1990", "5/24/1990", 
"5/25/1990", "5/26/1990", "5/27/1990", "5/28/1990", "5/29/1990", 
"5/30/1990", "5/31/1990", "6/1/1990", "6/2/1990", "6/3/1990", 
"6/4/1990", "6/5/1990", "6/6/1990", "6/7/1990", "6/8/1990", "6/9/1990", 
"6/10/1990", "6/11/1990", "6/12/1990", "6/13/1990", "6/14/1990", 
"6/15/1990", "6/16/1990", "6/17/1990", "6/18/1990", "6/19/1990", 
"6/20/1990", "6/21/1990", "6/22/1990", "6/23/1990", "6/24/1990", 
"6/25/1990", "6/26/1990", "6/27/1990", "6/28/1990", "6/29/1990", 
"6/30/1990", "7/1/1990", "7/2/1990", "7/3/1990", "7/4/1990", 
"7/5/1990", "7/6/1990", "7/7/1990", "7/8/1990", "7/9/1990", "7/10/1990", 
"7/11/1990", "7/12/1990", "7/13/1990", "7/14/1990", "7/15/1990", 
"7/16/1990", "7/17/1990", "7/18/1990", "7/19/1990"), dia_da_semana = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), mes = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L), ano = c(1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 
1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 
1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 
1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 
1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 
1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 
1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 
1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 
1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 
1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 
1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 
1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 
1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 
1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 
1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 
1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 
1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 
1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 
1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 
1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 
1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 
1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 
1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L), analise = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 78, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 56.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 36.23, 0, 0, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 59.74, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 78, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, 100, 66.46, 100, 56.01, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 100, 100, 72.23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, 100, 100, 78, 
100, 100, 100, 44.46, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 59.74, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 56.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 
100, 100, 54.97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 56.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, 75.35, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
200L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: QUando diz *mês*, significa *ano e mês*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui estão duas soluções, uma para cálculos das porcentagens de valores por ano/mês e a outra só por mês.

### Por ano/mês

Contam-se as linhas com `count` duas vezes, sem e com o filtro de a coluna `analise` estar entre 75 e 100. E juntam-se estes dois resultados com `left_join`. Depois é só dividir as colunas de contagens.

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(
  dados %>% count(ano, mes),
  dados %>% filter(analise > 75 & analise < 100) %>% count(ano, mes),
  by = c("ano", "mes"),
  suffix = c(".total", ".entre_75_e_100")
) %>%
  mutate(porcentagem = 100*n.entre_75_e_100/n.total)
#   ano mes n.total n.entre_75_e_100 porcentagem
#1 1990   1      31                1    3.225806
#2 1990   2      28               NA          NA
#3 1990   3      31                1    3.225806
#4 1990   4      30                1    3.333333
#5 1990   5      31               NA          NA
#6 1990   6      30               NA          NA
#7 1990   7      19                1    5.263158
```

### Só por mês

Basta retirar a coluna `ano` do código acima.

```
left_join(
  dados %>% count(mes),
  dados %>% filter(analise > 75 & analise < 100) %>% count(mes),
  by = "mes",
  suffix = c(".total", ".entre_75_e_100")
) %>%
  mutate(porcentagem = 100*n.entre_75_e_100/n.total)
#  mes n.total n.entre_75_e_100 porcentagem
#1   1      31                1    3.225806
#2   2      28               NA          NA
#3   3      31                1    3.225806
#4   4      30                1    3.333333
#5   5      31               NA          NA
#6   6      30               NA          NA
#7   7      19                1    5.263158
```

### Nota

Em ambos os casos, se não forem precisas as linhas sem dados (não há `analise` entre os valores pretendidos) basta usar `inner_join` em vez de `left_join`.

Comment: Rui Barradas obrigada pela resposta! Demorei para retornar pois não estava dando certo inicialmente, mas depois funcionou. Só não entendi a nota final que você colocou. "Em ambos os casos, se não forem precisas as linhas sem dados (não há analise entre os valores pretendidos) basta usar `inner_join` em vez de `left_join`. Como assim se "não forem precisas"?

Comment: @Bruna A 2ª, 5ª e 6ª linhas têm `NA`'s, quer essas linhas? Se não as quiser, use o `inner_join`.

Comment: Havia entendido precisas com sentido de "acuracidade". Obrigada!!!